# How to calculate the "Evidence" for Naive Bayes text classification?

Tags: machine-learning, python, naive-bayes-classifier, text-classification

I'm trying to write a Naïve Bayes text classification from scratch in Python, but I can't quite grasp what I should do to write the actual classifier.

One question that popped up was: "What formula do you use?"

Do you use the Bayes Rule/Theorem? Or do you use another equation? This information had conflicting answers (or as I thought) on different articles that I read.

Another question that popped up was: "How do you calculate the evidence?"

One article told me that I just don't calculate the evidence, and another one told me to do it, but never said how. The way I understand it, it's

P(X)*P(X1)...(P(XN)

But what's P(X)? How do you calculate that in text classification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Naive Bayes assumes feature independence so to obtain a w sentence's probability for C1 class you should multiply the probabilities of the words that make up the w sentence. The multiply thing you mentioned comes from here.
- And another thing, as you see below when you divide P1 to P2 P(w)'s will cancel each other out so you don't need to think about the evidence.
- Lastly there will be a logarithm process in order to handle very small numbers and you should use laplacian smoothing method to prevent zero dividing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer!